# Connection issues with PS4 Controller on PC

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, windows-10

When I connect my PS4 controller to my Windows 10 PC with the USB cable nothing happens. There is no light or anything. Occasionally, my computer says "The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and windows does not recognize it. Try reconnecting the device. If Windows still does not recognize it, your device may not be working properly."

I couldn't find a way around this and decided to try Bluetooth. Sometimes it would work and others not. Now it doesn't work at all. Please help.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're actually asking. Are you trying to connect your PS4 to your PC through Bluetooth, or the controller? Your entire explanation makes it seem as though you want to connect your PS4 to your PC, but you've tagged controllers. Please try to clean up your question a bit so we can better understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well you can try and follow the [instructions here](http://windowsreport.com/ps4-controller-windows-10/)

Answer (score 7):

I use a PS4 controller on my Windows 10 PC which is working fine. However I was at the same point as you.

The solution to my problem was working over Bluetooth.

- I use the Asus USB-BT400 stick to connect with the controller.
- When you connect your DualShock 4 controller to a PlayStation 4 via a USB cable, the controller automatically pairs with the console. To connect your PlayStation 4 controller with a PC, you’ll need to put it in Bluetooth pairing mode.
- make sure to reset the controller (if already connected to another device)
- press the "PlayStation" button and the "Share" button together until the lightbar starts flashing white to enter pairing mode.
- go to your Bluetooth settings on the computer and try to connect the controller. If it is not shown try to restart the Bluetooth on your computer.

This is how it worked for me. Most games are working fine. However, sometimes it shows the xBox controlls ingame.

[**Here**](http://www.howtogeek.com/240152/how-to-use-a-playstation-4s-dualshock-4-controller-for-pc-gaming/) you can find some usefull tips.

Let me know about your results or tell me if something is unclear, hope this helps. Greets

**Edit**

Today I‘m always using the open source tool DS4Windows because I ran into troubles using my dualshock controler in some games, mainly struggled with Steep. You can download it from Github:
https://github.com/Jays2Kings/DS4Windows/releases