# How to resolve PS4-controller issues in Steep on Windows?

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, steep

I‘m using a Dualshock controller with my Windows gaming computer. [In this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/291875/171769) I described how this is done and it also represents my current setup. However, while this works just fine with most of my games it doesn‘t with Steep! Sometimes the game won’t recognize or would just loose connection with the controller.

Sadly this happens quite randomly. But since it only happens in Steep I don’t think that I‘m causing the problem.

Has someone experienced similar issues? I’m happy with any kind of help and recommendations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Steam Controller feature, as mentioned [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/460920/discussions/0/1484358860950185316/)?

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn't seem to have any effects :/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Steam, then the problem can be fixed:
Go into your game library, <kbd>right-click</kbd> Steep, go into Properties, and search for the 'Steam Input Per-Game Setting'. Set it to 'Forced off', and restart the game.

Comment: @Wrigglenite why the edit? I somewhat get the removal of the html tags, even though I think it improves the legibility of the answer and that as a minor personal touch it shouldn't be redacted, but why the change into quotation marks?

Comment: @Joachim The kbd tags are for keyboard inputs, not all kinds of user inputs, so they shouldn't be used here. Apostrophes do not signify quoting, so they shouldn't be used here.

Comment: @Wrigglenite I beg to differ, the ' is as much a quotation mark as ", but I use the latter when I quote written text or speech, not the names or titles of buttons and functions, but feel free to go through my history of answers and edit them, leaving all the posts that actually need editing to fix spelling errors and the like to others. And I realize 'kbd' stands for keyboard, but there are many instances of them being used to emphasize someone is talking about buttons in a more general sense, and I'm not aware of any good reason to not employ them as such.

Comment: @Joachim No, misusing tags and punctuation is always a bad idea. It's the same reason [we don't use code tags for emphasis](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7437/143571). [Apostrophes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe) are not used for quotations, so they should not be used as such. Keyboard tags *mean* keys on a keyboard, so they should not be used for anything else.

Comment: [Quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) can be singular markings, too, so there is no question of 'misuse'. I agree with the fact we shouldn't use code tags for emphasis (which we had a discussion about way back), but you can't extrapolate that to the use of other tags, especially since [there's been consensus](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/422/222022) about its use for other buttons.

Comment: @Wrigglenite The ' button on a keyboard functions as both an apostrophe and a single quote.  It's not exclusively an apostrophe.

Comment: @Joachim Feel free to make a new question on meta, this is not the place to discuss this.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Likewise.